# How to loop through an array, and get some data from database Angular 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have the following array in component class (Angular 5):

```
this.collectionAdmins = ['uid_73hd', 'uid_38ng'];
```

Since I have  tables in my database(firebase) with users info, I want to loop through the `this.collectionAdmins` array, retrieve each user information from the database, So will be able to display that info in the template.

```
'uid_73hd': {
  "bio": "about me info",
  "email": "email2@gmail.com",
  "status": "online",
  "uid": "uid_73hd",
  "username": "mary"
},
'uid_38ng': {
  "bio": "about me info",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "status": "online",
  "uid": "uid_38ng",
  "username": "john"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you're using `firestore` and `angularfire2`, you can using this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md | if you're using `firebase`, you can apply this solution (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md) with promise.all or observable combination operator like combineLatest, zip, etc

Comment: Am using firestore. I see the tutorials....still trying to figure out how that suits my case

Comment: e.g: we're using (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) on `users` table, the code will look like this: https://jsbin.com/sunitojaho/edit?js

Comment: Can you add your comment as answer? it worked fine as I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you’re using Firestore and AngularFire2, we can using following solution:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';

export class YourComponent {
  collectionAdmins = ['uid_73hd', 'uid_38ng'];


  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

    const abs = this.collectionAdmins
      .map(id => afs.doc<User>(`users/${id}`).valueChanges()); // users table, replace with your real table
    this.collections$ = combineLatest(abs);
  }
}
```

p/s: some other operators to combine observable: forkJoin, zip. Or Promise.all if you want to using Promise instead of Observable.